# How do I properly set up and cite a bibliographic entry from a bibtex file?

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I'm getting an `undefined control sequence error` when I typeset my Latex document that cites an article in a linked BibTex library. How to fix?

I have set my typesetter to `pdfLaTeX` > `BibTex8`, and path to the `*.bib` file where my citations are stored set to:

```
\bibliography{../../../Documents/BibtexLibrary/BibtexLibrary}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

The BibTex entry in `*.bib` file is:

```
@article{mcclusky2001,
  Author = {McClusky, Bjornstad, Hagar, King, Meade, Miller, Monastero, Souter},
  Date-Added = {2016-05-27 19:28:56 +0000},
  Date-Modified = {2016-05-27 19:36:26 +0000},
  Journal = {Geophysical Research Letters},
  Keywords = {Coso},
  Number = {17},
  Pages = {3369-3372},
  Title = {Present day kinematics of the Eastern California Shear Zone from a Geodetically Constrained Block Model},
  Volume = {28},
  Year = {2001}}
```

Citation in Latex input:

```
  "...the context of recently \citet{mcclusky2001} mapped surface..."
```

From LaTeX output:

```
  "...the context of recently mcclusky2001 mapped surface..."
```

Comment: Do you know the basic compile procedure for bibtex stuff? As far as I can see, `\citet` is only for natbib `\cite` for general bibtex.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, to use the macro `\citet`, you need to load the `natbib` package. For details on how to use that package and the macros it provides, you may refer to its manual/documentation at [texdoc.net](http://www.texdoc.net) or from the command prompt/terminal type `texdoc natbib` in your computer.

Further, you have to use `and` to separate the author names instead of comma. So instead of

```
Author = {McClusky, Bjornstad, Hagar, King, Meade, Miller, Monastero, Souter},
```

you need

```
Author = {McClusky, Bjornstad and Hagar, King and Meade, Miller and Monastero, Souter},
```

More details on this can be found in [taming the beast](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwia_NCmsPvMAhULq48KHfK3D9wQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftug.ctan.org%2Finfo%2Fbibtex%2Ftamethebeast%2Fttb_en.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHP-cT1-Ko9wdCyx7j6FlX69M-ZYg&sig2=3E2KF6zWvGD4gVaPyILc9g). It is always better to put the style well before i.e., the line `\bibliographystyle{plainnat}` be added before the `\bibliography{BibtexLibrary}`. Last, when you load the `natbib` package, better use the styles provided by it -- use `plainnat` instead of `plain`.

Here is your code snippet in the form of a MWE. Here the `filecontents` package and environment are used just for this demo and you don't need them in your actual example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{BibtexLibrary.bib}
@article{mcclusky2001,
  Author = {McClusky, Bjornstad and Hagar, King and Meade, Miller and Monastero, Souter},
  Date-Added = {2016-05-27 19:28:56 +0000},
  Date-Modified = {2016-05-27 19:36:26 +0000},
  Journal = {Geophysical Research Letters},
  Keywords = {Coso},
  Number = {17},
  Pages = {3369-3372},
  Title = {Present day kinematics of the Eastern California Shear Zone from a Geodetically Constrained Block Model},
  Volume = {28},
  Year = {2001}}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
"...the context of recently \citet{mcclusky2001} mapped surface..."
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{BibtexLibrary}

\end{document}
```

BTW, don't use `bibtex8` for compiling, use `bibtex`. This will be enough. So the compilation sequence will be

```
pdflatex yourfile
bibtex yourfile
pdflatex yourfile
pdflatex yourfile
```

where `yourfile` is yourfile.tex, your actual `.tex` file name.

Comment: The `author` field contains eight [8!] separate authors. `McClusky, Bjornstad and Hagar, King and ...` isn't correct.

Answer (score 1):

Your objectives aren't entirely clear. As you're using the `plain` bibliography style, which can only produce numeric-style citation call-outs, there seems to be little point in using `\citet`, which is a macro provided by the `natbib` package for the purpose of creating textual-style authoryear citation call-outs.

If, on the other hand, you do want to create authoyear-style citation call-outs and hence do want to use `\citet` (and possibly `\citep` as well), you should (a) load the `natbib` package with the option `authoryear` and (b) switch from the `plain` to the `plainnat` bibliography style.

Separately, you should fix two major issues in the bib entry. First, the `author` field is badly mangled. Second, you need to do something to ensure that the substring "Eastern California Shear Zone" in the `title` field won't get lowercased. Regarding the former issue: the author field currently reads

```
Author = {McClusky, Bjornstad, Hagar, King, Meade, Miller, Monastero, Souter},
```

To separate the authors, don't use commas; use the keyword `and`. Incidentally, you're missing the first names of all eight [!] authors. A quick Google search shows that the `author` field really should be rendered as

```
Author = {Simon C. McClusky and S. C. Bjornstad and Bradford H. Hager and 
          R. W. King and Brendan J. Meade and M. M. Miller and 
          F. C. Monastero and B. J. Souter},
```

Second, the `title` field currently reads

```
Title = {Present day kinematics of the Eastern California Shear Zone 
        from a Geodetically Constrained Block Model},
```

A quick scan over the abstract of the publication reveals that "Eastern California Shear Zone" must be rendered in uppercase. (If nothing else, the word "California" should never be lowercased, right?) This won't happen by default, though, as both `plain` and `plainnat` practice "sentence style" for the contents of `title` fields: All letters of the entire field except for the very first one (here: "P") will be converted to lowercase. To override this setting, you need to encase the substring in question in a pair of curly braces. Thus, do write the field as follows:

```
Title = {Present day kinematics of the {Eastern California Shear Zone} 
        from a Geodetically Constrained Block Model},
```

With this setting, the words "Geodetically", "Constrained", "Block", and "Model" will all be rendered in lowercase; presumably, this is just fine.